# dosent understand how sort works

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparable

I'm trying to understand how the comparable `compareTo` method sort the input. Below is the `compareTo` method implemented:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Name n) {
    int lastCmp = lastName.compareTo(n.lastName);
    return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : firstName.compareTo(n.firstName));
}
```

The input array to the `Collections.sort` method is:

```
Name nameArray[] = {
    new Name("John","Smith"),
    new Name("Karl","Ng"),
    new Name("Jeff","Smith"),
    new Name("Tom","Rich")
};
List<Name> names = Arrays.asList(nameArray);
Collections.sort(names);
```

I don't understand what values are taken in to the `compareTo` method. (n.lastName and lastname) in which order?

Comment: The Collections sort method sorts your Name data based on your compareTo method.  The compareTo method is called as many times as necessary with two Name instances until all of the Name instances are sorted.  In your 4 instance example, the compareTo method could be called as many as 6 times.

Answer (score 1):

The Collections.sort() method uses different algorithms to sort depending on the collection length and type (I think...)

The compareTo method should return negatives, 0, or positives if the object is less-than, equal or greater-than respectively.
the lastName variable refers to the Last Name in the Name class, composed of firstName:String and lastName:String.

The method first compares the lastName (object of type String) to the lastName of the passed object "n" (of type Name). If it is different than 0 (meaning not equal) return that value. If it is equal then compare the first name and return that.

So it is only comparing the two strings (firstName and lastName of the Name objects).

Comment: public static Comparator<Student2> StuRollno = new Comparator<Student2>(){
  public int compare(Student2 s1, Student2 s2){
   int rollno1 = s1.getRollno();
   int rollno2 = s2.getRollno();
   
   //For ascending order
   return rollno1-rollno2;
   }};                           in this code how would i know if  rollno1-rollno2; sorts in ascending or descending order, since i do not know what will be s1 and s2 because the collection algorithm are different?

Comment: @user2892493: o1 - o2 is ascending, o2 - o1 is descending, assuming o1 and o2 are ints.  The people that wrote the Java sort methods were pretty smart, and considered all of your concerns when they wrote the code.  Here's an experiment.  Write your very own sort method **without using a compareTo method or it's equivalent**.  Let us know when you've completed the experiment.

Comment: Gilbert: im not sure if i understand w@ ur saying. how to write a string sorting method without using  compareTo method?